# Type annotations for full class hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, class, type-hinting, python-3.10

Suppose we have the following code:

```py
class Base:
    a: int

class Derived(Base):
    b: int

print(Derived.__annotations__)
```

Running this script in all recent versions of python will print `{'b': <class 'int'>}` (that is, the class members we explicitly defined in `Derived`. In python 3.10, using `inspect.get_annotations(Derived)` will result in the same output.

My question is, how do I get the type annotations for *all* the members of `Derived`? I'd like some function that outputs `{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>}`. This seems like a common enough use case that there should be a built-in function to do this, but I haven't found any.

I'm running Python 3.10, so recently added functions are good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), not raw annotation inspection:

```
import typing

full_hints = typing.get_type_hints(Derived)
```

This will also resolve string annotations, and recursively replace [`Annotated[T, ...]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) with `T`. Use cases that are interested in non-type-hint annotations can pass `include_extras=True` to `get_type_hints` to preserve `Annotated` annotations.